# Table View doesn't reload while using Tabbar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am using tab bar.
When i selected first tab bar icon, here we will add some task and save into coredata object.
Then, i selected second tab bar icon, here table view doesn't reload data.
When i tapped on any button in the second view controller and going to another view controller screen and then pop view controller or come back to that screen. Then the table view show the data which i added.

Why table view doesn't reload the data when i add task and going to second view controller ?

Constant.swift

```
 var tasks: [Task] = []
 var filterTodayTask: [Task] = []
```

CoreData.swift

```
 class CoreData {
        static func filterTodayTask(filteredObject: String) -> [Task]
            {
                let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()

                var user: [Task]? = nil

                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date_from == %@", filteredObject)
                fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

                do {
                    user = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    return user!
                }
                catch {
                    return user!
                }
            }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
@IBAction func btnCreate(_ sender: Any)
    {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Are you sure you want to save this task?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in

            //Function used to save the details in Core Data Models
            CoreData.saveData(tfCategory: self.tfCat, tfTask: self.tfTask, tfDateFrom: self.tfDateFrom, tfDateTo: self.tfDateTo, tfTimeFrom: self.tfTimeFrom, tfTimeTo: self.tfTimeTo, tvDesc: self.tvDesc, tfTag: self.tfTag, tfReminder: self.tfReminder)


        }

        let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(actionCancel)
        alert.addAction(actionOK)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

secondViewController.swift

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
        {
            super.viewWillAppear(true)

            tblToday.reloadData()
            tblTomorrow.reloadData()
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        if tableView == self.tblToday
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TodayTaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TodayTaskTVCell
            cell.tfTime.isEnabled = false
            cell.tfRepeat.isEnabled = false
            //cell.lblColor.backgroundColor = strColor

            if isFiltered
            {
                print("Entered Today Button")

                TextFieldCalender.imgWithinRepeat(textField: cell.tfRepeat)
                TextFieldCalender.imgWithinTime(textField: cell.tfTime)

                let filteredResult = filteredTask[indexPath.row]
                cell.lblTask.text = filteredResult.task_name
                cell.tfTime.text = filteredResult.time_from

                return cell
            }
            else if isToday
            {
                print("Entered Today Button")

                TextFieldCalender.imgWithinRepeat(textField: cell.tfRepeat)
                TextFieldCalender.imgWithinTime(textField: cell.tfTime)

                let filteredResult = filterTodayTask[indexPath.row]
                cell.lblTask.text = filteredResult.task_name
                cell.tfTime.text = filteredResult.time_from

                return cell
            }
            else {
                //This can execute every time when the view is loaded for the first time.
                print("Entered Today Button")

                TextFieldCalender.imgWithinRepeat(textField: cell.tfRepeat)
                TextFieldCalender.imgWithinTime(textField: cell.tfTime)

                let filteredResult = filterTodayTask[indexPath.row]
                cell.lblTask.text = filteredResult.task_name
                cell.tfTime.text = filteredResult.time_from

                return cell
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Check your datasource array....and also check have you connected dataSource and delegate to tableview...?

Comment: @MahendraGP all are okay

Comment: try to reload in main queue.

Comment: @ravi.p i tried but not response

Comment: Have you override the viewWillAppear of UITabBarController without calling super.viewWillAppear inside. If yes, then please call the super.viewWillAppear inside.

Comment: copy paste tblToday.reloadData()  tblTomorrow.reloadData() to override func viewWillDisappear(_:) on the second view Controller
(The best way to aproach this problem is with rxSwift and an observable but this is another talk)